# Set A Javascript Variable so it can be checked by an onunload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onunload

I have a page that shows incoming stock parts so serial numbers can be entered. I have a JQuery Ajax function that updates the database and hides the line id a serial no is input. No problems here.

I also send an email on unload, again no problems.

What I want to do is to is set a variable to 1 after my ajax function so I can see that there has been an amendment to the stock, and then in the `onload` function I can see the status of that variable and decide whether or not to send the email.

my set the serial number is :

```
function updateField(what) {
    serial = document.getElementById('serialno_' + what).value;
    po = document.getElementById('po_' + what).value;
    entry = what;
    if (serial != "") {
        $("#totalitems").load("stock_ajaxserial.php?id=" + entry + "&stock=" + serial + "&po=" + po);
        $("#tr_" + what).hide("slow");
    };
}
```

and my `onunload` is simply:

```
function SendEmail()
{
    $.get("stock_in_email.php?po=<?php echo $row_rs_po['entry']; ?>&id=<?php echo $row_rs_po['Order_id']; ?>");
}
```

Comment: so what is the question? and you should consider using jquery, it would simplify a lot on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just one little thing that i have noticed: Why are you setting the var "entry" to "what" instead of using "what" directly? Is "entry" considered to be a global javascript variable? If you are using "entry" just in your function i strongly reccomend to do "var entry = what"! This is because the javascript will search for a global variable "entry" without the var-keyword.

Comment: @Jim can you tell me if you were able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you could use cookies to set data on the `unload`, and read data during the `onload` later

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global var outside your code and check it's value inside. IMHO isn't the cleanest way of doing what you need, but I hope it is what you want.

```
var ajaxReady = 0;
function updateField(what) {
    serial = document.getElementById('serialno_' + what).value;
    po = document.getElementById('po_' + what).value;
    entry = what;
    if (serial != "") {
        $("#totalitems").load("stock_ajaxserial.php?id=" + entry + "&stock=" + serial + "&po=" + po, function() {
            ajaxReady = 1;
        });
        $("#tr_" + what).hide("slow");
    };
}
```

and At your `onunload` function:

```
  function SendEmail()
  {
      if (ajaxReady) // ajax must be done to send e-mail
          $.get("stock_in_email.php?po=<?php echo $row_rs_po['entry']; ?>&id=<?php echo $row_rs_po['Order_id']; ?>");
  }
```

Hope it helps.